# How can you block a thread until one of many channels becomes readable?

Tags: multithreading, select, rust, channel, blocking

I'm trying to have a thread (in rust) that listens to multiple channels at once.

In Ada, something similar can be done using a `select` statement:

```ada
loop
    select
        accept Task1 do
            -- do something
        end Task1;
    or
        accept Task2 do
              -- do something else
        end Task2;
    or
        accept Task3 (param : Parameter) do
              -- do a third thing, with a given parameter
        end Task3;

        -- etc.
    end select;
end loop;
```

This will block the thread until one of the Task methods is invoked remotely.

I'd like to do something like this in rust, but the following would be terrible, as I'd be wasting a ton of CPU time:

```rust
loop {
    if let Ok(message) = rx1.try_recv() {
        // do something
    }
    if let Ok(message) = rx2.try_recv() {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to *block* the thread entirely until one of the resources is updated. But I can't just switch out the thread, as I'd need some way of waking it back up when one of the resources is updated (which is what I *think* `recv()` does).

What's the normal way of solving this kind of problem in Rust?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible with the standard library channels. However you can do it with [crossbeam](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam) channels and [`select`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.1/crossbeam/macro.select.html):

```
select! {
    recv(rx1) -> msg => { /* Do something */ },
    recv(rx2) -> msg => { /* Do something else */ },
}
```